# MS SQL bulk user and database creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bulk

I'm exploring options to setup a SQL 2016 database server to support teaching students database fundamentals. There will be close to 200 students on the course.

I'd like to automate the creation of all the user accounts and associated database via a script - this means the database for each user needs to be created at the same time. Basically each student's user login name and database will be named as the student's ID. Login authentication will be SQL authentication, not Windows as the lab PCs are not on AD.

If anyone could point me in the direction of any scripts I could modify or use it would be extremely helpful - basically if I go down this route I'll need to do it every year so scripting would be optimal.

Thanks
D.

Comment: what usernames are you going to use? you can use dynamic sql and a cursor to create them

Comment: It would be handy if the details could be pulled in from a csv or excel sheet with columns for login, password, and database.  Username same as login name.

Comment: Then use powershell in connection with CREATE USER command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dynamic Sql and using while loop we can loop the student names and create database and logins.Hope it helps you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#USerTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #USerTable

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#USerNameINSERT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #USerNameINSERT

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#PasswordsINSERT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #PasswordsINSERT

--ADD Your student Names Passwords in a single  line as below
DECLARE @Usernames NVARCHAR(max) = 'Stud1,Stud2,Stud3,Stud4'
    ,@Password NVARCHAR(max) = 'Password1,Password2,Password3,Password4'
    ,@Usernameselect NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@DatabaseNameselect NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@PasswordSelect NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@Usernameselect1 NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@DatabaseNameselect1 NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@PasswordSelect1 NVARCHAR(max)


DECLARE @USerName TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,Usernames NVARCHAR(max)
    ,Passwords NVARCHAR(max)
    )

INSERT INTO @USerName (
    UserNAmes
    ,Passwords
    )
SELECT @Usernames
    ,@Password


SELECT ID,UserNAmes INTO #USerNameINSERT
FRom  (
SELECT Row_number()Over(Order by (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS UserNAmes
            FROM (
                SELECT ID, CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(UserNAmes, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS UserNAmes
                FROM @USerName
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY UserNAmes.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
            )DT

SELECT ID,Passwords  INTO  #PasswordsINSERT
FRom (
SELECT  Row_number()Over(Order by (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Passwords
            FROM (
                SELECT CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(Passwords, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Passwords
                FROM @USerName
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY Passwords.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)

)DT

SELECT u.ID
    ,u.UserNAmes
    ,u.UserNAmes+'Db' AS DatabaseName
    ,p.Passwords
INTO #USerTable
FROM #USerNameINSERT u
INNER JOIN #PasswordsINSERT p ON p.ID = u.ID


DECLARE @minId INT
    ,@maxId INT
    ,@SqlQuery NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@SqlQuery1 NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@SqlQuery2 NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @minId = MIN(ID)
    ,@maxId = Max(Id)
FROM #USerTable

WHILE (@minId <= @maxId)
BEGIN
    SELECT @Usernameselect = UserNAmes
        ,@DatabaseNameselect = DatabaseName
        ,@PasswordSelect = Passwords
    FROM #USerTable
    WHERE ID = @minId

    SET @SqlQuery = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameselect
    SET @SqlQuery1 = 'USE [' + @DatabaseNameselect + ']'
    SET @SqlQuery2 = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @Usernameselect + ' WITH PASSWORD=N''' + @PasswordSelect + ''' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO'
    SET @SqlQuery = ISNULL('', 'GO') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @SqlQuery 
                    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @SqlQuery1 
                    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Go' + + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @SqlQuery2

    --EXEC (@SqlQuery)

    PRINT @SqlQuery

    SET @minId = @minId + 1
END
```

Comment: Brilliant! Tweaked this slightly to map login and add database role and all worked great, also added in MAXSIZE during database creation. Thanks again :)

Comment: you are welcome ! At the time of adding UserName and password make sure you have to  enter same count

Answer (score 0):

Use CREATE LOGIN command.
Following example will create user myDBUser.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [myDBUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'myPassword' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[myDB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
```

And of course create DB user for such login

```
USE [myDB]
GO
CREATE USER myDBUser FOR LOGIN myDBUser;
```

Comment: Thanks for response Marek - I need to automate this for 200 users, so would need to use variables to pull the list of users in from a file such as csv or excel sheet, database needs to be created at same time for each user.

Comment: With powershell you can easily [read data from csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)

Comment: And then run [database query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289310.aspx) on the results you get.

Comment: What I do in such cases is to use Bulk Insert to load names into a holding table, and then create a query along the lines SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE [' + UserName + 'DB];' FROM HoldingTable.  Run the Query, copy the results into a query window and run the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work, you might need to alter the dynamic SQL bit around the login as its a bit thrown together.

```
--Create table for bulk insert
Create Table UserNameCSV (UserID int, UserName Varchar(100))

--Insert login names from C:\csvtest.txt
BULK
INSERT UserNameCSV
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO

-- Run Cursor
Declare @UserName Varchar(100)

Declare db_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
Select UserName from UserNameCSV

OPEN db_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_Cursor INTO @UserName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @Sql varchar(max) ='CREATE DATABASE ' + @UserName
DECLARE @Sql1 varchar(max) = 'USE [' + @UserName + ']'
DECLARE @Sql2 varchar(max) = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @UserName + ' WITH PASSWORD=N''myPassword123!'' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON'

EXECUTE(@Sql)
EXECUTE (@Sql1)
EXECUTE (@Sql2)


FETCH NEXT FROM db_Cursor into @UserName

END

CLOSE db_Cursor
DEALLOCATE db_Cursor
```

Comment: Thanks for this, tried it out but having trouble with the csv parsing, will have a further play with it.