Create users dynamically from a table variable
I'd like to create a T-SQL script that iterates through all the values of a table variable, creates users, and grants them access.
Think of it like this:
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(150))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('User0'), ('User1'), ('User2'), ('User3')

DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
WHILE @cnt < COUNT(@MyList)
    CREATE USER [@MyList[@cnt]] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
    GRANT XXXX to [@MyList[@cnt]]
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END

Is that even possible?

Yes you can but you would have to use dynamic SQL.  So you would build out your create user statement into a SQL variable.  Then execute the dynamic SQL variable with the scripts in them.

Could you write an example as an answer?

Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754437/ms-sql-bulk-user-and-database-creation

Does this answer your question? A table name as a variable

I ll have a look of both of them! Thanks a lot!!

SQL Server 2022
